# Pushing without a commit in Mercurial or Git

Tags: git, mercurial, dvcs, push

Seems like for both Mercurial or Git, if I don't commit first, then I can't push?

So if I don't commit (when not ready yet), I can't push to a remote server to back up my code?  The code is in a notebook computer, being carried around, which can be somewhat fragile being carried around.

Answer (score 17):

You are *always* ready to commit.

Commit often.  Commit to a work in progress branch and distribute it as widely as you feel.

When you get to the state that you're currently referring to as "ready to commit", examine the divergence of your branch from the upstream, do a `rebase -i` to clean it up and make it look like you want.

This will be easier, safer, and just generally give you better results than trying really hard to get everything perfect before committing.  Remember:  A commit doesn't necessarily represent a desired permanent state of the universe.  It's just somewhere you are.  How you publish it is up to you.

git makes it *very* easy to publish a `do-not-look-at-me` branch for your work in progress that you can later move into your official codebase at whatever point and in whatever form you think best suits you.

Answer (score 7):

Just make a new throw-away branch.

Commit half-baked changes into that branch, and push that branch.

When your changes are ready, squash your half-baked commits (using `rebase`), and merge the result into your `master` and delete the throw-away branch. (You can delete a branch from a remote repository using `git push origin :branch` – note the colon before the branch name.)

There is never a reason not to commit your changes, although there may be reasons not to commit *to a particular branch* when they’re not ready yet.

Answer (score 3):

That's correct.  The purpose of push is to share one or more commits with other repos.  Neither are primarily intended as backups (though some people use them for that).

There are plenty of dedicated backup tools and online services.  See 
[Online backup for personal use](https://superuser.com/questions/2476/online-backup-for-personal-use) for a list.

Comment: having a separate back up system can seem a bit of a hassle.  If only Git or Mercurial can let people set up a repo for uncommitted push.  Something like `git push --uncommitted ssh://somewhat/peter/tmp`

Comment: @Jian, again, these are not backup programs.  The intended idea is to make one or more meaningful commits, which you then share.  It wouldn't make much sense to have a repo that contained both commits and works-in-progress.

Comment: The "separate backup system" can be a repository, too. This is how I work : I code in my personnal repo (where I commit often), and I have a central repo to share my work with my colleagues (where I push, but less often). In order to backup the work I do in my personnal repo, I have a third repo : a hook in my personnal repo performs a push on that backup repo each time I commit. That way, the backup operation is completely transparent (the time penalty is negligible).

Comment: For comparison, TFS allows for uncommitted remote backups:  Shelvesets.

Answer (score 2):

That's correct; you can't push uncommitted changes. However, just because your changes aren't ready yet doesn't mean you can't commit them. I have no experience with Mercurial, but with Git, you can amend a commit (`git commit --amend`) to modify it after it has been committed. You can also make a series of commits and then do an interactive rebase to combine them into a single commit. Or you can just make commits as necessary and not worry about making sure your history is completely pristine.

Comment: As explained at [RECOVERING FROM UPSTREAM REBASE](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html#_recovering_from_upstream_rebase), `--amend` can become a major hassle.  Anyone that pulls from the pre-amend version has to modify their history once they get the amended version.

Comment: That's only relevant if the repository he's pushing to is shared. If he's just using it for backup purposes, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: ...and the branch is official.  If you push to a branch called `my-wip` and someone thinks they should build a product around that, then they deserve confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Lemme see if have the scenario correct. You have...

1. some uncommitted edits in your working directory that you'd rather not commit yet,
2. some unpushed changes in your local repository,

...but your annoying boss taps you on the back and says, "Hey!  When are you going to push that change you mentioned in the staff meeting?  We're all waiting for it!"  He's standing there waiting for you do it, so how do you get him out of your hair quickly and easily?

This is easy.  You want to be using the [MQ extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MqExtension).  It's bundled with the standard Mercurial installation.

First add it to your `.hgrc` file.

```
[extensions]
mq =
```

To stash your uncommitted edits in a patch queue entry, do this:

```
$ hg qnew stash
$ hg qpop
```

Now push your older commits, so your boss will get off your back.

```
$ hg push
```

Finally, restore your working directory like so:

```
$ hg qpush
```

At this point, you still have the patch recorded in your patch queue.  It's just marked as "applied" now.  Finish editing your code, then do this to update the patch with your finished edits and a commit log message, then finalize the patch into a changeset:

```
$ hg qrefresh -m"Commit message goes here."
$ hg qfinish stash
```

That's the basics, but there's a whole lot more you can do if you want to get really fancy.  The MQ extension is like a whole new world of revision control hiding underneath the Mercurial repository.  It's like the Git stash, but more flexible and marginally less confusing.

Learn, mutate, evolve!